# viewFlipper.showPrevious(); shows previous view but do not update listner

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a `viewflipper` with 2 layouts. when i use `viewFlipper.showPrevious();` after using `viewFlipper.showNext();`. it does shows previous layout but does not update background listener. That is not previous layout become unresponsive to touch. but if i touch at the places on the screen where buttons are there in 2nd layout then it responses to them and not to current screen's view elements. i don't know what is causing this problem. please someone help.

```
    islide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (temp == true) {
                temp = false;
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.move);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.move2);
                // Show the next Screen
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            } else {
                temp = true;
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.move4);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.move3);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where the listener is created? Also are you creating the two views from a single xml layout file or programmatically?

Comment: I am using single layout and two views inside it. i followed this tutorial. http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

Comment: for listener using below code. 
islide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (temp == true) {
     temp = false;     viewFlipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move); viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move2);
     // Show the next Screen
     viewFlipper.showNext();
    } else {
     temp = true;     viewFlipper.setInAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move4);   viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move3);
     viewFlipper.showPrevious();
    }
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your problem could be, considering the question is not very thorough. But i can provide you with my example of a slide view that implements several views and buttons on those views. Hope i can help:

The XML for the separate view layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/StoreCatItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/credit_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/credit_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/credit_button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/credit_type"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

With this, you define what each view will look like in the viewFlipper.

This is the main XML, the activities xml that contains teh viewFlipper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/backMain_Tit"
    android:layout_margin="6dip" >

</ViewFlipper>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backMain_StM"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Back" />
```

And finally at the end we have the code that will be in your activity. This code adds views to teh viewFlipper and allows you to define paramaters such as TextView contents and button names:

```
// PerkView
    View PerkView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.store_category, null);
    viewFlipper.addView(PerkView);
    Button perkButton = (Button) PerkView.findViewById(R.id.StoreCatItem);

    // TitleView
    View TitleView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.store_category, null);
    viewFlipper.addView(TitleView);
    Button titleButton = (Button) TitleView.findViewById(R.id.StoreCatItem);

    // ProfileView
    View ProfileView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.store_category, null);
    viewFlipper.addView(ProfileView);
    Button profileButton = (Button) ProfileView
            .findViewById(R.id.StoreCatItem);
```

And last but not least, you can add aseperate listener to each button created above:

```
perkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Your Code
        }
    });
```

Hope this helped a little :P